# Format for integers in my Account magento

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account, currency, plugin

As I show the values of the purchase orders without the decimals

[image]

I want you to show them this way $ 23,747

Answer (score 1):

For change `order total` formatting, you can copy `app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/templates/order/recent.phtml` template to your module directory and modify line 42 (formatPrice -> formatPricePrecision)

From:

```
<td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
```

To:

```
<td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_order->formatPricePrecision($_order->getGrandTotal(), 0) ?></td>
```

---

Note, that you need to redefine new template to `Recent Orders` block using `xml layout`.